# query results from 4 different tables with only 1 known value

Tags: php, mysql, oop

right now im working on a query and for my brain this is an overload since i just started php and mysql.

I have 4 tables "Seminar, subscription, unsubscription, user" and i need a little data from all of them.
"Seminar, title", "subscription, active, datetime", "user, firstname, lastname" and "unsubscription, reason" Now I have only 1 value that i can use to get all this data and this is the seminar ID now i was wondering if that is enough to get the data from all tables.

Im really lost I hope someone can help me through this mess.

Thanks in advance

I got a little knowledge from inner joins, left joins etc.

Here is my ERD
http://img594.imageshack.us/img594/8923/erdk.png

Comment: Yes if all 4 tables are associated with foreign key concept. We can use MYSQL joins

Comment: Show us your tables structure.. We need to know what relation fields you have so we can provide you with answer..

Comment: subscription got user_id and seminar_id as FK's and unsubscription got subscription_id as FK

Comment: updated my question with ERD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look? Typed on ipad so sorry for typos.

```
Select
    Sem.title,
    Sub.active,
    Sub.datetime,
    U.firstname,
    U.lastname,
    Unsub.reason

  From
    seminar sem

    Inner join  Subscription sub  on sub.seminar_id = sem.id

    Inner join user u on sub.user_id = u.id

    Left join unsubscription unsub on sub.Id = unsub.subscription_id

   Where
     Sem.id = your-search-value-here
```

I'm assuming there won't always be an unsubscription, so this is a left join on to that table.

All others are inner... Meaning a subscription isn't complete without a user AND a seminar.

But If you want details about a seminar, regardless of if a user is subscribed, then your join to user should be changed from INNER to LEFT too.

And If a seminar can exist without ANY subscriptions, and you want such seminars included in the results, you should also change the join on subscriptions to be LEFT.

Note that Any fields selected from a left joined table, where no result was acquired on that table for that seminar, will be null.

Comment: My pleasure mate. I've changed the order of the table joins since first posting, so that I could better explain your options re left or inner joins. If you need to follow those instructions to suit your needs, you should use the current version of the SQL. Thanks for the accept, I appreciate it. Good luck with it.